# Transparent image not appearing in menu

Tags: css, transparency, background-image

My page is [here](http://mmicet.yazminmedia.com/install).

My drop down navigation css is [here](http://mmicet.yazminmedia.com/css/dropdown.css).

I'm trying to add a transparent png image, image [here](http://mmicet.yazminmedia.com/images/bkg_menu.png), to the drop down portion of the menu. However, it's not appearing.

I thought adding a "suboptions" class to the dropdown ul would do the trick, along with setting CSS for that dropdown, but it doesn't seem to be working.

HTML in question:

```
<ul class="suboptions">
            <li><a href="/faqs" title="CET Color Frequently Asked Questions">F.A.Q.'s</a></li>
            <li><a href="/install" title="CET Color Installation &amp; Site Prep">Installation</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS in question:

```
#menu li ul.suboptions {
background-image: url(/images/bkg_nav.png) !important;
background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have float for the `<li>`

You have to clear the float, after `<li>` or apply bg image for li.

**EX:1**

*add this to your css*

```
#menu li ul.suboptions:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

#menu li ul.suboptions {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] #menu li ul.suboptions {
    display: block;
}

* html #menu li ul.suboptions {
    height: 1%;
}
```

**EX2:**

*add this to **`#menu li ul.suboptions li`** class*

```
#menu li ul.suboptions li {
background-image: url(/images/bkg_nav.png) !important;
background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex - Thanks for the response. I have your current example #1 on the site, but it's not working as expected. I also attempted #2 with no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I  changed  in "http://mmicet.yazminmedia.com/css/dropdown.css"  
-->line 95:

"#menu li ul.suboptions { ..."   to --- >  "#menu li ul.suboptions li {"

Comment: Thanks Alex. I just changed that as well, but still no dice.

Comment: Alex - Your code above works. I had to go through line by line and see what was causing it not to appear transparent on my end. I had to remove the background-color declarations in several places before it worked as expected. Thank you!